# Is an IDP required for renting a car within the EU if you have a standard EU format license?

Tags: driving, car-rentals, eu, driving-licenses

I'm looking into a car rental in Netherlands (Alamo) and their terms and conditions state that:

> International Driving Permit needed along with original domestic licence.

Does this also apply to standard format EU licenses? My Czech license only has Czech text, but it does follow the standard field numbering format. I'm looking for a general answer that covers all of the EU - if at least some of the companies ask EU license holders for an IDP, it would be prudent to get one.

Also note that this question isn't about police checks - I am aware that EU members must recognize each other's licenses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course not.

This doesn't address the question of EU licenses directly, but it leads to the same result:

> ## Heb ik een internationaal rijbewijs nodig?
>
> U dient in het bezit te zijn van een geldig rijbewijs uit het land van herkomst. Een internationaal rijbewijs is alleen noodzakelijk indien het rijbewijs is uitgegeven in niet romaans schrift.

Translation:

> ## Do I need an international driver's license?
>
> You must be in possession of a valid driver's license from the country of origin. An international license is only necessary if the driver's license is issued in other than the Latin script.

Source: https://www.alamo.nl/veelgestelde-vragen/

Comment: There's some strange variation among the different language versions of the linked site. In the English version it just says "Every driver needs to have a valid drivers licence from the country of origin.". The German version corresponds to the English version, the Spanish version corresponds to the Dutch version, and the French version redirects to Alamo's Belgian site!

Comment: The only EU country I ever heard about that requires or at least asks for IDP is Italy. And even there it is mostly rumor and not proof.